# Hero image begin bigger when scrolls only on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

My problem is, I think, simply but is driving me crazy.

Only on mobile, when i scroll the page, the hero image begin just a little bit bigger. That's cause an horrible effect on the page which seems to recharge something. 
When I try something on my PC for see the responsive design nothing happens. It happens just when I try it on a real mobile.

http://www.thefactoryhair.netsons.org/ 
That's my website.
The error is more visible in the secondary page.
The hero image has got an height with VH.

Help me please :(

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Hi @Gianno. What mobile device are you testing on?

Comment: @frits i'm testing on S7 edge.. But I dont think that's the problem...

Comment: @CBroe Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Relevant code belongs into the question; if you post an external link only, the question will become worthless to future readers, once the content behind that URL changes. So also go read how to create a [mcve] please.

Comment: @CBroe thats the real problem. I dont know what part of the problem makes that problem happen.. So the only way is to check out the page I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to remove `vh` as your measurement. It sounds harsh, but unfortunately it's thanks to modern day mobile browsers.

When you scroll down a page on a mobile browser (I've just tested with Chrome on my phone), the URL bar shortens. As soon as this happens, the viewport height increases, causing all of your elements that use `vh` to "jump".

Use a measurement such as em, px, or percentage. If you specifically need to set something based on the height of the screen (meaning none of the other options are even feasible) you can try to adjust the screen size using jQuery.

Here's some sample code you could use to adjust an element height once, meaning it won't adjust when the viewport resizes, only when the page reloads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fullscreen').css({'height':$(window).height()*1});
});
```

You can replace the `#fullscreen` with whatever element you want to adjust, and replace the `1` with `0.7` to make it 70% of the window height instead of 100.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: I've waited to test it and it has worked like a charm!!! You have saved me! Thank u so much! <3

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please remember to accept the answer :)